# How to get summary statistics of Logistic Regression in Rapid miner?

Tags: logistic-regression, rapidminer

I am new to the RapidMiner interface, I want to find out whether the variables in my classification model are significant or not based on the `p` value.

In R I do this `summary(model)`  and I will get the summary statistics that contains the `p, t & standard error values`.

But the same thing I am not able to find in the RapidMiner interface.
which Operator will give me this summary statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model output of the `Logistic Regression` operator gives details of the model.

Here's a toy example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="8.0.001">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="8.0.001" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_data" compatibility="8.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data" width="90" x="179" y="136">
        <parameter key="target_function" value="simple polynomial classification"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="h2o:logistic_regression" compatibility="7.6.001" expanded="true" height="124" name="Logistic Regression" width="90" x="313" y="136"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Data" from_port="output" to_op="Logistic Regression" to_port="training set"/>
      <connect from_op="Logistic Regression" from_port="model" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Running this should give this output.

[image: Logistic Regression model output]